# How to use Numpy to compute the outer contour of binary image and fill inner area?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use Numpy (without any other packages) to find the outer contour of the 1st binary image and fill the inside area so it looks like the 2nd image, basically filling the holes of the wheels but I don't know how to do it. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75063839/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi, I don't need code-writing, any ideas are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is similar to the "fill bucket" tool in most common pixel-based editors like MS Paint; I'd imagine if you google around how to write your own "fill bucket" tool, you'll get ideas to get started. Figure out how THAT tool works first, then tweak it for your special case?

Comment: yea thanks I will go check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to implement the [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm. The high-level idea is:

1. Pick an origin point, say (0, 0).
2. Run a breath-first or depth-first search from the origin to collect a list of points with the same RGB value. You pick a pixel (starting with the origin), find it's horizontal and vertical neighbours, and if the colour is the same, repeat on the new pixel.
3. Set every pixel that wasn't identified in the search to white.

This operation has been implemented many times before. If you are not opposed to using a new library, take a look at `findContours` and `drawContours` in [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html). OpenCV operates on numpy arrays so you won't have to transform the data.